# Input more data on .bat file

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I know nothing about coding in Batch files. I need to have a .bat running a command, but then I need it to ask me for an address that goes in. The thing I need to run is below:

```
C:\Python27\python example.py -a ptc -u IsaacElenbaas -p mypasswordhere -l "LOCATION" -st 10 -H 0.0.0.0
```

So I need to run a bat file, then have it ask me for the location, and than have it run the command with that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: -1  you should look up how to get input in a batch file and at least attempt to, and do so with a simpler example than your one. Then try to apply that to your one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comfortable just simply typing the location when you run the batch file, you can substitute *%1* for the item you wish to appear in your batch command e.g.:

```
C:\Python27\python example.py -a ptc -u IsaacElenbaas -p mypasswordhere -l "%1" -st 10 -H 0.0.0.0
```

Assuming you wanted "LOCATION" to appear as in your example you would type:

```
 nameof.bat LOCATION
```

which would produce your original example i.e.:

```
C:\Python27\python example.py -a ptc -u IsaacElenbaas -p mypasswordhere -l "LOCATION" -st 10 -H 0.0.0.0
```

*%1* corresponds to the first item listed after the name of your batch file when you type it at the command line i.e.

```
nameof.bat item_one(%1) item_two(%2) item_three(%3) ....
```

If you want a complex substitution (multiple items at once) use %* (percent asterisk) e.g.:

```
C:\Python27\python example.py -a ptc -u IsaacElenbaas -p mypasswordhere %* -st 10 -H 0.0.0.0
```

If this was invoked with:

```
nameof.bat -l "LOCATION"
```

it would again produce your original example i.e.:

```
C:\Python27\python example.py -a ptc -u IsaacElenbaas -p mypasswordhere -l "LOCATION" -st 10 -H 0.0.0.0
```

## Caveats

Note that you do need to be careful about your use of double quotes"", but as long as you know what is in your batch command you should be fine.

The only real drawback to this method is that if you don't type anything corresponding to the substitution at the command line when you invoke the batch file, your substitution will be blank e.g.:

```
C:\Python27\python example.py -a ptc -u IsaacElenbaas -p mypasswordhere -l "%1" -st 10 -H 0.0.0.0
```

Used with:

```
 nameof.bat
```

would produce:

```
C:\Python27\python example.py -a ptc -u IsaacElenbaas -p mypasswordhere -l "" -st 10 -H 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

#### So I need to run a bat file, then have it ask me for the location

Use `set /p` to prompt for and enter a value:

```
SET /P variable=[promptString]
```

- The `/P` switch allows you to set a variable equal to a line of input entered by the user.

  The Prompt string is displayed before the user input is read.

Try the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /p _location=Enter a location: 
C:\Python27\python example.py -a ptc -u IsaacElenbaas -p mypasswordhere -l "%_location%" -st 10 -H 0.0.0.0
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.